# ORDER BY in WHERE EXIST query works incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql

ORDER BY does not work with where exist

I have SQL generated by ORM, but it sorts data incorrectly

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
WHERE (
      EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM `passports`
  WHERE `users`.`id` = `passports`.`user_id`
  AND DATE_ADD(
       birth_date,
        INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
                                               > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
        YEAR)
     BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  ORDER BY DATE_ADD(
     birth_date,
            INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date)
                     + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
            YEAR
       );
)
```

ORDER BY does not work
But subquery sorts correctly

```
    SELECT *
    FROM  passports
    WHERE  DATE_ADD(
        birth_date,
               INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date)
                     + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
               YEAR
          )

         BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  ORDER BY DATE_ADD(
            birth_date,
            INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date)
                     + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
            YEAR
       );
```

What is wrong in my code, how to make it work

I get an unsorted array of users(first query), But the sorted array of their passports ordered by soonest birthdays(subquery), I expect the output of the sorted array of users according to subquery rule.

Comment: can you show the table structure of `users` and `passports`? Is `birth_date` a column of `users` or `passports`?

Comment: birth_date is column of passports
users:`|id|name|surname`, passports: `|id|user_id|birth_date|`

Answer (score 1):

It´s because you have the order by in the wrong place. In the subquery, the system orders the rows, but then in the outer query, they don´t get any order (in SQL, even if they are ordered, the SELECT doesn´t return the information in that order. You need to order by if you want an specific order). You should take out the order by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users`
WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT *
         FROM `passports`
         WHERE `users`.`id` = `passports`.`user_id`
               AND DATE_ADD(birth_date,
               INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
                                                   > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
               YEAR)
         BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)    
         )
ORDER BY DATE_ADD(birth_date,
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
                YEAR)
```

**EDIT**

As you said, it doesn´t find the column `birth_date` because it is in the `passports` table. I would change all your query to use an inner join instead of EXISTS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users`
inner join `passports` on `users`.`id` = `passports`.`user_id`
WHERE DATE_ADD(birth_date,
               INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
                                                   > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
               YEAR)
         BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
 ORDER BY DATE_ADD(birth_date,
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birth_date)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(birth_date),1,0)
                YEAR)
```

If you don´t need all the columns, in the `SELECT *`  you will have to change the * by the names of the columns you need (`users.id, passports.birth_date`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The main question is why do you need order by clause inside EXISTS?  ORM is definitely generating wrong SQL. It may be better to open new question with your ORM code so that the issue would be worked out.

you cannot expect your output data to be sorted in this scenario. The subquery gets sorted inside exists not on the main query.

**simple example**

```
select * from tb 
where exists (
  select x from tb2
  order by x
);
```

only subquery with tb2 is sorted, but since it is used in EXISTS clause there is no effect to the output

Comment: You right, better to open new question about Eloquent ORM